# Powershell getting lines from a text file after the last occurrence of a string

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have a robocopy log file that I am working with, and I need to extract the summary lines using powershell.  The issue that I am running into is that the summary is not always the same length in number of lines.

Assuming the log file looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Tue Dec 01 06:55:11 2015

   Source : C:\Source Path
     Dest : E:\Destination Path

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /TEE /S /E /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /NP /R:2 /W:2 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
List of files here
List of files here
List of files here
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
     Dirs :       945         0       945         0         0         0
    Files :     10118         4     10114         0         0         3
    Bytes :   1.245 g   323.9 k   1.244 g         0         0         0
    Times :   0:00:17   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:17

    Speed :             5264920 Bytes/sec.
    Speed :             301.261 MegaBytes/min.

    Ended : Tue Dec 01 06:55:28 2015
```

I can statically get the last 11 lines of the file with the command `$summary = Get-Content $log | Select-Object -last 11 | Out-String`, but the two speed lines are only listed if data has actually moved, which otherwise results in the last of lines of the file list.  Ultimately not a huge problem, but it doesn't look very pretty.

Instead of a set number of lines, how can I get the last lines from the file, after the last (or 4th, there are always 4) occurrence of the delimiter `---------------`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, but I feel like there has to be a better way.  The first command finds all the delimiters, and outputs the line numbers to the `$finds` array, then the second line, using the last element in the `$finds` array as the starting point for extracting the summary.

Hope this helps someone else!

```
$finds = Get-Content $log | Select-string "--------------" | Select-Object LineNumber

$summary = Get-Content $log | Select-Object -skip $finds[-1]."LineNumber" | Out-String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content $log | Select-String 'Total' -Context 0,20
```

Explanation: `Select-STring` looks for any line containing 'Total'. The parameter `-Context 0,20` tells it to display up to 20 lines after the matching line (and zero lines before).

If you copy a file like 'sales_total.txt', this line will match also. To prevent that, you could make the matching string more explicit. Use the complete line for example.

Comment: The one downside that I see here is the context parameter will add blank lines after EOF to make it 20 lines.  I tried something similar already, but depending on the situation it would work.  I'm kind of picky on my formatting for this project.

Comment: No, it doesn't add blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-Content $log -Delimiter ('-'*78) |
Select -last 1
```